# Unwanted page header inserted into subreport on execution (but not preview)

Tags: crystal-reports

My legacy report will be imported into and executed from a medical practice management application to be executed. The report is nothing more than a details section with a subreport, one to a page.

These subreports has a consecutive report header and a group header. There is no page header anywhere in the section expert dialog. Running a preview of the report executes exactly as it appears. But when the report OR the subreport is executed in any way there is suddenly a wide blank Page Header. This header doesn't appear in the Section Expert (even with *Show all headers on drilldown*) so I can't suppress it.

None of the sections have any paging options selected, and the page header is constantly inserted *only* into that particular subreport. I don't see any differences between the options or sections. How can I resolve this?

I'm using SAP BusinessObjects Crystal Reports 2013 support pack 5.

Section Expert of subreport:

- Report Header(keep together)
- Report Header a
- Report Header b
- *(Page Header inserted here when executed, not visible otherwise)*
- Group Header 1 (suppressed, keep together) [not necessary, not sure
  why author included, but removing the group doesn't fix the problem]
- Group Header 2 (keep together)
- Group Header 3 (keep together)
- Details (keep together)
- Group Footer 3 (keep together) [not used, 1 pixel high]
- Group Footer 2 (keep together) [not used, 1 pixel high]
- Group Footer 1 (keep together) [not used, 1 pixel high]
- Report Footer (suppressed)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct the issue by running the report in the third-party program, exporting the subreport, suppressing the "new" page header in the subreport-as-report, and then importing the new version of the subreport into the original report.

Page header no longer inserts itself at execution.

Comment: in this case, It seems like a bug